# kartik\Select2 in GridView Filter show id instead of name

Tags: javascript, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I have a Gridview and in the dropdown I decide to implement a select2 dropdown using ajax, has the page was taking too long to load, after implementing the ajax the performance improved a lot and works fine the ajax search.
My issue is when I select a name from the list the page reloads and gets the data from that id that I selected, but in the filter header, it shows the id instead of showing the name.
The code below is only for the user, but the column for Organization and Message also have the same issue.

[Filters ID's instead of name](https://prnt.sc/iic54k)

view/index.php

```
 $formatJs = <<< 'JS'
 var id_user = function (id_user) {
 return id_user.id ? id_user.id : id_user.text;  
 }
 JS;
 $this->registerJs($formatJs, \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD);
 ... 
  [
        'attribute' => 'id_user',
        'label' => Yii::t("app", "User"),
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return Notification::findOne($model->id)->idUser->name;
        },
        'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
        'filterWidgetOptions' => ['options' => ['placeholder' => ''], 'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true, 'minimumInputLength' => 3,
            'ajax' => [
                'url' => Url::to(['user-list']),
                'dataType' => 'json',
                'data' => new JsExpression('function(params){return{q:params.term};}'),
                'cache' => true,
            ],
            'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
            'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('id_user'),]
        ],
    ],
```

Controller.php

```
public function actionUserList($q = null, $id = null) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '']];
    if (!is_null($q)) {
        $query = new Query;
        $query->select('id, name AS text')->from('tbl_user')->where(['like', 'name', $q])->limit(10);
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        $out['results'] = array_values($data);
    } elseif ($id > 0) {
        $out['results'] = ['id' => $id, 'text' => User::find($id)->name];
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: you need to add the code for the action `user-list` that is feeding the data to the `select2`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Done. This method is similar to the other columns but calls the correspondent models.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that the answer is quite late, but I myself encountered such a problem. Maybe the solution is useful to someone.

In order for the value to appear instead of the identifier, you need to use  `initValueText`.

First, we need to get the user from the selected identifier.

```
$filteredUserId = ArrayHelper::getValue(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('UserSearch'), 'user_id');
$filteredUser = $filteredUserId ? User::findOne($filteredUserId) : null;
```

For some reason, I have a slightly different filter format, maybe the version is different or both options work. I will give an example from my code:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'user_id',                                
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
    'filterWidgetOptions' => [                                   
        'initValueText' => $filteredUser ? $filteredUser->getName() : null,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'closeOnSelect' => true,
            'minimumInputLength' => 1,
            'ajax' => [
                'url' => Url::to(['user/user-list']),
                'dataType' => 'json',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => '...'],
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return $model->user() ? $model->user()->getName() : null;
    },
],
```